# PatternSyntaxException when using Unicode category names in regex

Tags: java, android, regex, unicode, uppercase

I am trying to detect whether a string consists of all uppercase characters in an Android app. `[A-Z]` as a character class is not sufficient as the letters may be decorated with diacritic marks and the like. I would like to use `\p{IsLu}+` for the pattern, but it constantly gives me a `PatternSyntaxError`.

However the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) advertises these Unicode category names. The API level my emulator is running is 11.

If I try my regex pattern on a regex tester like e.g. on [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) it works fine.

This is the logcat output:

> 12-06 22:08:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       12-06 22:08:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(737): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
>       12-06 22:08:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(737): \p{isLu}+
>       12-06 22:08:07.854: E/AndroidRuntime(737):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in your actual code you have written `isLu` instead of `IsLu`. However, the `Is` is just an alias anyway. The usual Unicode property is simply `\p{Lu}`.